# Verificar se há um produto dentro do estoque

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, classes, if

Estou fazendo um trabalho da faculdade onde preciso fazer um sistema de lojas com varios estoques.

Cada loja está associada a um estoque especifico, porem se nao houver o produto no estoque daquela loja, pode verificar se há o produto em outros estoques.

O que eu estou tendo dificuldade é justamente de como verificar se há o produto dentro do estoque da propria loja.

Alguma solução?

OBS: não há necessidade de usar banco de dados, é um projeto simples

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Produto mouse = new Produto(1, "Informatica", "Mouse", 15.00m);
        Produto teclado = new Produto(12, "Informatica", "teclado", 15.00m);

        Estoque e1 = new Estoque(10);
        e1.CadastrarProduto(mouse, 10);
        //e1.CadastrarProduto(teclado, 20);
        Estoque e2 = new Estoque(20);
        e2.CadastrarProduto(teclado, 20);
        Estoque e3 = new Estoque(30);

        Estoque e4 = new Estoque(40);

        Loja l1 = new Loja(100, "Loja A", e1);
        Loja l2 = new Loja(200, "Loja B", e2);
        Loja l3 = new Loja(300, "Loja C", e3);
        Loja l4 = new Loja(400, "Loja D", e4);

        List<Loja> loja = new List<Loja>();
        loja.Add(l1);
        loja.Add(l2);
        loja.Add(l3);
        loja.Add(l4);

        List<Estoque> estoque = new List<Estoque>();
        estoque.Add(e1);
        estoque.Add(e2);
        estoque.Add(e3);
        estoque.Add(e4);


        foreach (var elemento in loja)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(elemento.NomeLoja);

        }



        foreach (var lojaL in loja)
        {
            //Pecorre todos os itens dos pedidos

            for (int x = 0; x < estoque.Count; x++)
            {
                if (estoque[x].IdEstoque == loja[x].IdEstoque)
                {
                    if (estoque[x].VerificaDisponibilidade(teclado))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("SIM");
                        Console.WriteLine(estoque[x].IdEstoque);
                        Console.WriteLine(loja[x].IdEstoque);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Nao ha estoque: {teclado.Id}");
                    }
                    //Console.WriteLine(estoque[x].VerificaDisponibilidade(teclado));
                    //Console.WriteLine(estoque[x].IdEstoque);
                    //Console.WriteLine(lojaL.IdEstoque);

                }
                else
                {
                    //throw new Exception($"Não há estoque do produto:{teclado.Id}");
                    
                }
            }
        }
}
}
}
```

Comment: *"Alguma solução?"* olá Victor soluções tem muitas, agora sem ver o código fica difícil ajudar

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Os produtos do stock devem ser guardados em uma lista de Produtos. Para encontrar um determinado produto basta percorrer o array e comparar o ID do produto com o ID procurado.

Se temos diferentes stocks, então devemos ter uma lista de Stoks, onde cada Stock contém uma lista de Produtos. Devemos então percorrer os stocks e para cada stock percorrer os produtos a procura do produto desejado.

Nos lembrando de verificar sempre a quantidade disponível.